# javascript objects to json string to php array -> POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, javascript-objects

Hey guys i really need help with this. i pass this json object to php..

```
var x = {};
x.xt = {};
x.xt.id = id;
x.xt.to = foo;

somearray.push(x);
```

convert object to json:

```
$.toJSON(x);
```

json string:

```
[{"x":{"xt":"9","to":"2"}}]
```

them i post this:

```
$.post(
    "temp/sop.php",
    { xa: somearray},
    function(data){
        console.log("response - "+ data);
});
```

server side:

```
$xtj = $_POST["xa"];
$encodedArray = array_map(utf8_encode, $xtj);
$asnk = json_decode($encodedArray);
```

This returns:

```
string(4) "null"
```

and this:

```
$asnk = json_encode($xtj);
```

returns:

```
null
```

the data base it is set to:

> UTF8

also when i test if it is an array, comes back true..

any idea how to solve this? thanks

also server side:

```
$xtj = $_POST["xa"];
$asnk = json_decode($xtj);
```

this returns:

```
NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST["xa"] is an array? and utf8_encode should be inside quotes, otherwise php will throw a notice (or warning).

Comment: try: `console.log(somearray);` just before $.post, and `var_dump($_POST['xa');` somewhere in the beginning of your php file.

Comment: if i echo the POST i get this:
[{\"x\":{\"xt\":\"4\",\"to\":\"2\"}}]
and console before $.post is this:
[{"x":{"xt":"9","to":"2"}}]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is `sop.php` just supposed to decode the JSON, re-encode it as JSON, and send it back or what?

Comment: sop.php it is just decoding JSON and passing the array to another method.But the thing it is. it worked fine on one server and local host. but when i moved to their final server it does not work.. even tho it does have the same settings

Comment: You say the database is set to UTF8 ... What database :) ?

Comment: @nl-x utf8_general_ci to be more specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using 
`if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $xtj = stripslashes($xtj);`
to lose the excessive escaping before trying to decode.

Comment: thanks mate that totally work. still dont get it. i have magic quotes off :S

Comment: guess not. try using `phpinfo()` to see which php.ini is actually being used (and to confirm that magic quotes is actually on). Then turn off the magic quotes in the php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

`$.toJSON(x)` does not do the conversion in-place; it *returns* the JSON, and you're just discarding it. You need this instead:

```
$.post(
    "temp/sop.php",
    { xa: $.toJSON(somearray) },
    // ...
});
```

Then, on the PHP side, you won't want `array_map` as it's not going to be an array until you decode the JSON:

```
$xtj = $_POST["xa"];
$encodedArray = utf8_encode($xtj);  // I'm not sure you need this, by the way.
$asnk = json_decode($encodedArray);
```

Comment: i get this on the console after response in javascript:
response - NULL

Comment: This is the what the POST recieve on the server:
[{\"cart\":{\"itemid\":\"4\",\"itemAmount\":\"1\"}}]
but after json_encode i get a null result

maybe magic_quotes?

Comment: too good to be good, not luck with that :-/ can the server settings mess with this, besides magic_quotes

Comment: @jycr753: Maybe. I haven't dealt with PHP in a while; I can't think of what would do it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you are converting to json string in JS (`$.toJSON()`).
And then in PHP you are again trying to convert to json string (`json_encode()`).
And you are using `array_map()` on something that is not an array but a string. (Try `echo $_POST["xa"];` to see the contents of it.)

Comment: my bad mate. just a miss spell :) but it is json_decode :) thanks for noticing it :)